# Get rows from Database from comma-separated value

Tags: php, mysql

I have comma-separated value I get from multi-select option which is the id of mysql rows. I want to display it but I'm getting 'Notice: Array to string conversion' error using explode. My database table has columns of 'id, url' .

below are my code:

```
$imageids = '1,2,3,4';
$id = explode(',', $imageids);

$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

foreach ( $id as $img ) {

   $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT url FROM kg_images WHERE id = :id');
   $query->bindParam(':id', $id);
   $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   echo '<img src="../content/uploads/'.$img[url].'">';

}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after great help from @Syscall, finally make it work. below is my working code:

```
$imageids = '1,2,3,4';
$id = explode(',', $imageids);

$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

foreach ( $id as $img ) {

    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT url FROM kg_images WHERE id = :id');
    $query->execute(array(
        ':id' => $img
    ));
    $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo '<img src="../kg-content/uploads/'.$data['url'].'">';

}
```

Comment: Note that there are examples out there of using IN() within the context of prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach()` use `$img` as value. So inside, you have to use `$img` instead of `$id` which is the array :

```
$query->bindParam(':id', $img);
```

Change also the following, because you have to use the result of your query instead of `$img` which is a number.

```
echo '<img src="../content/uploads/'.$data['url'].'">';
```

Comment: Good catch! Thanks @Syscall I updated my code to 

$query->bindParam(':id', $img);

but got an error Notice: Use of undefined constant url - assumed 'url' in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 19

My line 19 is echo '<img src="../kg-content/uploads/'.$img[url].'">';

Comment: Okay so I added quote to my $img['url'] to solve the Notice: Use of undefined constant url. that solves the problem. Now I got 

Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' error

Comment: after changing `$img['url']` to `$data['url']`, now im getting Notice: Undefined variable: data

Comment: @RaffyM `$data` is not the result of `fetch()`?

Comment: finally make it work! Thanks for your help! I change my pdo from bindParam to Fetch as you mentioned fetch(). Thanks again!